# How can i make a custom URL like link provider

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension for VS code (typescript).
I want to add a URL-like link opener.

I basically want to pass a regex or something and a callback function.
when a person `ctrl+click`s on a text that matches the regex, I want it to call my function and pass the text that was captured by the regex.
I also want it to show the little pop-up that says `Open file in editor [ctrl+click]`.

Is there any documentation or already-made code that implements this?

I asked on the microsoft/vscode Github repo, and they led me to [link provider example code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/98346fc4fa81067e253df9b32922cc02e8b24274/contentprovider-sample/src/extension.ts#L16),  but I don't really understand the example code.